# Lufthansa 48h guarantee fare

Tags: bookings, fees-and-charges, lufthansa

I have a problem with Lufthansa. I have booked a flight with them using the 48h Fare guarantee.

The price of my trip was 889 eur total. Then, as I was still discussing with my wife the trip I have ticked the 48h guarantee option and filled in the form with credit card details etc. In the page was clearly written that I will be charged 30  EUR just if no action will be taken within 48h. With surprise, as soon I have confirmed, my credit card was charged for 130 EUR. Then I regularly received the email with instructions how to confirm the reservation, but any mention to this charge. I then very fast confirmed the trip, following the instruction in the first email and then I was charged for the full amount of the trip (as per above 889), it means that the 130 were not taken in consideration as advance.

I thought the the 130 eur will disappear from the card so I've waited for the night but next morning the charge didn't disappear. Then I have opened a case to the customer relation and now I am already at the second email, where the customer assistant is stating that the charge is legit. I copy and paste what did she wrote:
1st email: 
" [...] Lufthansa’s fundamental objective in letting you reserve a seat on a desired flight at a guaranteed price and giving you the option of waiting up to 48 hours to confirm the reservation is to increase the flexibility available to you. Therefore, you can lock in a flight at a low fare, but still have enough time to finalize plans and/or to coordinate with other travellers in your party.
We therefore hope for your understanding that this amount is non-refundable since this is a valid charge even though you confirmed your ticket only after 6 minutes. You may contact the reservations team again for further information regarding the Secure Your Fare option as your concern was misunderstood by them [...]"

2nd email:
"[...]Kindly be advised that Secure your Fare is a feature of Lufthansa's website to place the amount of your desired flight on hold for a price. Placing a ticket on hold is not free of charge. As stated on the disclaimer, "With the Secure your fare option, you can reserve the selected flights for 48 hours at the specified price." This means that after paying EUR 130, you have 48 hours to pay for the amount of the ticket that you placed on hold using this feature [...]"

Now I am waiting for the third answer, but I really do not know how to get out from this and have my money back.

Comment: I don’t see a way out of this. You agreed to be charged €39 if you hadn’t confirmed, €130 plus the flight cost if you do confirm. The LH site says the fee is non-refundable “With the Secure your fare option, you can reserve the selected flights at the price specified for up to 48 hours. No ticket will be issued and you will not be charged for the reservation. A cancellation fee of $39.00 will be charged if you cancel your reservation or take no action within the 48 hour time limit. The "Secure your fare" fee is non-refundable.” https://www.lufthansa.com/us/en/baggage-and-other-fees

Comment: You might be too quick. Payment systems are still designed for once a month statements, not for online banking. Wait a week and it might disappear. Are you sure those €130 is for Lufthansa? My understanding is that you either pay the ticket price or €30 (if you cancel or don't  do anything within 48h).

Comment: @Traveller, First of all I have confirmed the booking within 48 hours. Anywhere is written that I confirm they will charge 130€.

Comment: @Anders, I am sure 130€ are for Lufthansa. I'll wait if they disappear. I understand the same like you. If I do not confirm within 48h I will be charged 30 eur, If confirm no additional fee will be applied